# Does "process" refer to "random experiment" in the definition of a statistical model?

Tags: probability-theory, definition

A statistical model can be represented as $\mathcal{(S,P)}$ where $\mathcal{S}$ represents a sample space and $\mathcal{P}$ a set of possible probability distributions on $\mathcal{S}$. One of the probability distributions in $\mathcal{P}$ is assumed approximates the "true" probability distribution induced by the ***process***. My question is if "process" in this context is synonymous to the idea of a "random experiment" represented as a probability space $(\varOmega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{P})$?

Comment: Normally a "random process" refers to a collection of random variables indexed on a totally ordered set, but here I presume "process" is referring to something else?

Comment: @ Math1000 Good point, I assumed when I read it that it is referring to something else, but I am not sure. I think it is referring to "the" underlying data generating process. A random experiment can be modelled using a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F, P})$, every time $(\Omega, \mathcal{F, P})$ is executed it generates one outcome. A sample space \Omega is all possible outcomes and is represented as \mathcal{S} in a statistical model $\mathcal{(S,P)}$. Might this (a random experiment) be what "process" refers to in the definition of a statistical model. I have still no clue... :/